# Is it OK to initialize a reference member with dynamically allocated memory?

Tags: c++

Am I causing a memory leak here or is it OK to do like this? Should I use a smart pointer member instead of a reference?

```
class A
{
public:

   A() : b_(*(new B))
   {}

private:
   B& b_;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You certainly are leaking memory; every `new` needs to be matched with a `delete`.

Unless there's a good reason for dynamically allocating it, you'd be better off just making `b_` an object. Otherwise, use a smart pointer as you suggest, or (not recommended) `delete` it in your destructor, remembering to make the copy constructor and copy assignment behave correctly. In the last case, it's valid (but a bit unusual) for it to be a reference rather than a pointer.

The decision really comes down to how you want the class to behave when you copy it. In the first case, it will copy the entire object; in the second, it will behave as defined by the smart pointer; in the third, it will behave as defined by the copy constructor/assignment that you implement.

Answer (score 1):

The language allows this, however, as you have it written, there is a memory leak. You have a `new`, but no corresponding `delete` - you need to write a destructor here, something like:

```
A::~A() {
    delete &b_;
}
```

Now, while this is legal, it is weird. A pointer will do just as well, and will probably convey better what's going on. A smart pointer would have saved you from a leak, and may be applicable.

Comment: And remember: if you have a non-trivial destructor, you nearly always need to sort out the copy constructor and copy assignment.

Comment: Then again... don't. If you want to manage dynamically allocated memory, make it explicit: use pointers. If you want to make it right, make those smart pointers. Hiding dynamically allocated memory behind a reference will just make it more complex to reason about the code when you or someone else has to work on it later.

Comment: @David: That is a better worded explanation of what I meant by "a pointer will ... convey better what's going on."

Comment: Thank you guys for all helpful advice. My conclusion is to use a const smart pointer instead of a reference.

Class A is my first attempt to make a DI containter flexible for various build configurations (I've seen a poor man's container should be avoided but I'm trying to get started with dependency injection), any advice/example on how to implement a poor man's container?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is allowed in C++.

Of course, it is more safe to use smart pointers.

Then You shouldn't worry about clearing allocated memory in destructor.

Like this:

```
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
   A() : p_b( new B() )
   {}
   someMethod() {
       return p_b->something();
   }
private:
   std::auto_ptr<B> p_b;
};
int main()
{
    A a;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have edited the answer to use syntax highlighting --select the block of code, then press in the small button `010...`. I have also made it more compact to make the best out of the screen real state. (I have just seen that I forgot to correct the `return` statement of `someMethod`... add a type there :)

Comment: `auto_ptr` won't behave quite the way you'd expect here - which bring us back to Mike's point about copy c-tors and assignment operators. Alternatively, you could use a `boost::shared_ptr`. All (`boost::shared_ptr`, this example, writing a copy c-tor that copies the object) behave differently, so you need to evaluate the situation to see which is right.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I would add to what has been said, is that even though you are allocating memory in the constructor which means that `b` will always start with a value, in the destructor I would change slightly what Justin wrote.  I always check for `NULL` before I call `delete` and then set the pointer to `NULL` after I free it.  In the destructor setting the pointer to `NULL` is kind of pointless, but is there just for consistency.

```
class A
{
public:

   A():b_(new B)
   ~A() { if (b) { delete b; b = NULL; } }
   {}

private:
   B* b_;

}
```

Comment: `delete NULL;` is a valid statement in C++: it does absolutely nothing.

Comment: I'd suggest you break that habit; checking for null, and setting to null, simply bloat the code for no purpose. And, once again, if you write a destructor you nearly always need to fix the copy semantics.

Comment: Good suggestion. Old habits die hard, but I will keep that in mind along with Thanatos's comment. Thanks.

Comment: Your class is buggy: you have forgotten to redefine the copy constructor and assignment operator as well than (in C++0x) the move constructor and move assignment operator. Lesson one of memory management: `delete` is a code smell, pick up a smart pointer.